# Sqlite - smart insert or replace query

Tags: sqlite

I have a question about **sqlite**.

Assuming I created a table:

```
CREATE TABLE GOODS(ID TEXT  PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, TYPE TEXT, VERSION INTEGER)
```

Then after a while I want to use 'insert or replace' like this:

```
insert or replace into GOODS(ID, TYPE,VERSION) values ('chrome_id', 'chrome', 15);
```

But I want this query to 'replace' iff old.VERSION < new.VERSION.

How can I do that?

Do I need to use **2** queries (it should looks like this:) ?

```
1. get row
if(row.VERSION < myVersion){
2. insert or replace ... 
}
```

I heard about trigger but I do think this the solution.
thx

Comment: NO. REPLACE INTO will INSERT the value if not found or UPDATE it if found. You need a single **command** (queries are only SELECT).

Comment: As far as I understand replace is: DELETE + INSERT.When I wrote "how can I do it?" I actually meant to a single command so what do you mean when you say that I need a single command what do you mean exactly ? @Rotwang

Comment: You need a single command (REPLACE INTO). What it does behind the scenes to accomplish your command is not your business. You tell it to execute **one** command, and it executes **two** for you.

Comment: So You saying that I need something like: replace into GOODS(ID, TYPE,VERSION) values ('chrome_id', 'chrome', 15) where VERSION < 15; but the syntax is not good @Rotwang

Comment: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html

Answer (score 1):

Use the SELECT form of the [INSERT statement](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html) to be able to control how many rows are inserted:

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO Goods(ID, Type, Version)
SELECT 'chrome_id', 'chrome', 15
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                  FROM Goods
                  WHERE ID = 'chrome_id'
                    AND Version >= 15);
```